# Why I am unable to fetch data from the table?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

There is table named `leagues`, created as :

```
CREATE TABLE leagues(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,lname VARCHAR(255),
                       season VARCHAR(255),PRIMARY KEY (lname),KEY id(id));
```

For which a mapping `hibernate xml` is :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="pojo.Leagues" table="leagues">
  <id column='lname' name='leaguename' type="string">  </id>
  <property column="id" name="id" type="integer" />
  <property column="season" name="season" type="string" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am trying to get data from the `leagues` table, but I am unable to. Here is the method that is meant to do it:

Query returns nothing and code never enters the loop.

```
public LinkedList<String> getLeagues() {
    String hql = "select leaguename from pojo.Leagues";
    lnames = new LinkedList<String>();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessFact = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessFact.openSession();

    Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
    List list = query.list();
    System.out.println("Heyyyyyyy:ll");
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Inside while block");
        Leagues lname = (Leagues)i.next();
        lnames.add(lname.getLeaguename());
    }
    return lnames;
}
```

Where am I making a mistake? Why I am unable to fetch data?

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in you DB? Have you tried to connect to the DB using available SQL enabled tool and perform select?

Comment: I think your session is not opened successfully. please check value of sess after sessFact.openSession() command to sure it is not null

Comment: @Mahmoud No, it is not null.

Comment: Did you check the configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml file? If you're sure that's correct then enable hibernate.show_sql=true this and check the SQL query actually running from the log.

Comment: Is the `leaguename` in query is as in `pojo.Leagues` ?

Comment: @sathya_dev Everything else works fine. I suspect the issue with the mapping xml

Comment: what is the output of the SOP that you have written. Please paste any errors that you are getting

Comment: @OO7 Yes, it is the same.

Comment: hibernate.show_sql=true, add this in configuration xml and check the actual query used. We may get an idea from it

Comment: @sathya_dev do i add as it is?

Comment: @sathya_dev Also, if I remove `pojo.Leagues` from hql and keep `Leagues` , I get no mapping file found exception

Comment: <property name="show_sql">true</property> add this within  <properties> tag along with other properties

Comment: <property name="show_sql">true</property>

Comment: pojo is pacakge name ,right? Have to use Fully qualified name

Comment: Yes, but it works fine for other classes where I do not use it.

Comment: @sathya_dev By what name will I see the result?

Comment: If ur PRIMARY KEY `(lname)`  then what is KEY `id(id)` ? I never seen this type of syntax in SQL query. Will u explain it ? I think ur mapping is not as per SQL query where u have made `id` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` & in mapping `<id column='lname'` Do u want this as `composite key` or  `lname` or `id` either of them is to be a primary key ?

Comment: @OO7 `id` is the index. I also think, the issue resides with the `xml`. How do I correct it?

Comment: Add `index="id"` in xml mapping.

Comment: @OO7 I added like `<property column="id" name="id" type="integer" index="id" />` but the same result

Comment: Did u able to get the query used to run from the logs?

Comment: @sathya_dev Yes. Under what name do I look for the result?

Comment: Try changing ur mapping to this form `<property name="id"><column name="id" index="indexName" /></property>`. Or try generating `hibernate.hbm.xml` using *Hibernate Code Generator* in editor like Eclipse. Check whether u get the same result as ur mapping ?

Comment: @OO7 Same result. But I have been getting a warning message along with the logs : `WARNING: no persistent classes found for query class: select leaguename from pojo.Leagues`

Comment: please paste your entire hibernate-cfg.xml for forum members to guide you

Comment: I think it's bcoz *u r using **pure SQL** query use **HQL** instead*. Then it look for packages in the query or set the scope of the `javax.persistence` to `provided`, if using maven.

Comment: or change query to `select lname from leagues`. or just *remove package name from ur query*.

Comment: Have a look my answer. May it helps u.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you didn't get any data from the DB is **you are using *pure SQL query*** & calling

```
Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
```

which works on HQL as per [`createQuery()` - Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)).

If you want to use pure SQL query then you must use [`createSQLQuery()` - Hibernate Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SharedSessionContract.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String))

```
String sqlQuery = "select leaguename from pojo.Leagues";
SQLQuery query = sess.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
```

or change your query in HQL format just like below

```
String hqlQuery = "from pojo.Leagues";
```

Comment: It should work fine with the pure SQL query and it is working fine now! `Blunder` : didn't include the mapping inside `hibernate.cfg.xml`
But thank you, for all the help.

Comment: Also, this query also forms a part of HQL. So terming it as not HQL, would be incorrect.